# Using Object Parameter to pull another Object

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12

Re-introducing myself to Angular, wanted to ask a question.
I am pulling appointment data into my fields, and I need to pull the user name up using the "UserId" parameter in the appointment object, and having that pull up the user using the "UserId" parameter in users, and THEN display the name. They're all coming into my console just fine, but how exactly do I write it in the frontend to do this?

```
        <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel class="content" *ngFor="let app of appointments, let i = index">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngFor="let user of users">
            <mat-panel-title>Image: </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-title ***ngIf="app.UserId === user?.UserId">Client: {{user?.ContactId}}**</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-title>Location: {{this.currentLocation}}</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-title>Date: {{app.StartDate| date : 'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-title>Time: {{app.StartDate| date : 'hh:mm'}}</mat-panel-title>
            <i class="material-icons-outlined" style="align-self: end">expand_more</i>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-description>
            <p>Desc: {{app.Description}}</p>
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Just to confirm you want to render the HTML based on using the UserId (to check through your array of users) to display a specific User Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your after is a `pipe` to filter through your data. Lets go through a simple example.

A `pipe` would look something like this **filter-user.pipe.ts**:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterUser',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterUserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(users: string[], filterUser: string): any {
    if (!users || !filterUser) {
      return users;
    }

    return users.filter(user => user === filterUser);
  }
}
```

Your `component` with your data of appointments and users **app.component.ts**:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  // your Appointments
  appointments: Appointment[] = [
    {
      name: 'Brolly',
      surname: 'Patel',
      date: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'Goku',
      surname: 'Smith',
      date: new Date()
    },
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      surname: 'Smith',
      date: new Date()
    }
  ];

  // your Users
  users: string[] = ['John', 'Brolly', 'Goku', 'Gohan'];
}

// Interface you may want to put in another separate file.
export interface Appointment {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

Keeping it simple to help you understand, I've rendered the following HTML **app.component.html**:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let appointment of appointments">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users | filterUser: appointment.name">
    {{user}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When you create your `pipe` remember to add it into your concerning `module` in the declarations array. (I say concerning module as it helps with lazy loading) **app.module.ts**:

```ts
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core';
import { FilterUserPipe } from './filter-user.pipe';
import { HelloFrameworkModule } from './hello-framework';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, FilterUserPipe],
  imports: [BrowserModule, CoreModule, HelloFrameworkModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Your output would be the following:

```
Brolly
Goku
```

So in your code example this is how it would look:

```ts
// Your HTML would roughly look like this:
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel class="content" *ngFor="let app of appointments, let i = index">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngFor="let user of users | filterUser: app.UserId">
      <mat-panel-title>Image: </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-title>Client: {{user?.ContactId}}**</mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-title>Location: {{this.currentLocation}}</mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-title>Date: {{app.StartDate| date : 'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-title>Time: {{app.StartDate| date : 'hh:mm'}}</mat-panel-title>
      <i class="material-icons-outlined" style="align-self: end">expand_more</i>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description>
      <p>Desc: {{app.Description}}</p>
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

// Your pipe would need modifying slightly as your using an object:
export class FilterUserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(users: string[], filterUserId: string): any {
    if (!users || !filterUserId) {
      return users;
    }

    return users.filter(user => user.UserId === filterUserId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now the ContactId is giving me an Unresolved variable error

Comment: Is your `users` object a `string` array if not, then change the type in the transform inside the `pipe` from `string[]` to `yourType[]`. Is it possible to see you code on stackblitz for me to double check if that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, so I think the issue is both users and appointments are object arrays, I just need to check userId for both of them and pull the first and last name of the user that matched the appointments userId. stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cgpsbv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I looked at your example and it works fine, also there is no `contactId` defined? did you forget to define it? Also with your stackblitz example, because the material package isn't installed it won't render. so I copied everything you put in html and replaced with `div` tag and it shows all the data as expected.

Comment: I changed contactId to firstName and lastName. Thank you for your help, I see it's working in the stackblitz but still not in mine. I may have an issue with my api. Thank you